# Why isn't there an SQL ops site in StackExchange?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

It seems to me, with some of the most popular database servers (Oracle, MS-SQL Server, MongoDB, PostgreSQL, MySQL/MariaDB) that it may serve to have a dedicated site for those servers?  Maybe just an "sql.stackexchange.com" site?

I was specifically wanting to find a canonical example of getting PostgreSQL setup with PLV8 and wasn't even sure where to ask.  In my case, Ask Ubuntu may have been best, I was just thinking with the number of database administrators, and devops types in this network that it would be a good idea to have a separate site.

There are many SQL ops questions that aren't OS specific, or aren't really development questions... where do these go?

Comment: I wonder if we could have sql.stackexchange redirect to dba.stackexchange

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe you are looking for

[image]

Their [help center](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) states:

> If you have a question about...
>
> - Database Administration including configuration and backup / restore
> - Advanced Querying including window-functions, dynamic-sql, and query-performance
> - Data Modelling and database-design, including referential-integrity
> - Advanced Programming in built-in server-side languages including stored-procedures and triggers.
> - Data Warehousing and Business Intelligence including etl, reporting, and olap
>
> …then you're in the right place to ask your question!

Comment: Thanks.. :-) that's what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Your question seems like it would be a perfect fit for http://dba.stackexchange.com, the Database Administrators Q&A site.